# How to formulate reference another sheets if i have list of sheets name in sheets1? On sheets

Tags: spreadsheet

How to formulate reference another sheets if i have list of sheets name in sheets1?
[image]

I want the value in cell b2 in each sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**INDIRECT() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=uk)

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!B1")
```